# Bash script not detecting mysqld is installed, but works when running manually

Tags: bash, shell

I have a backup script for my servers, and there is a switch to backup mysql databases if `mysqld` is installed.

```
# If flag is set and executable is installed
if [[ "$flag_s" -eq 1 ]]; then
  printf "STATE: Detected flag -s\n" >> "$logfile"
  if [[ -x "$(command -v mysqld)" ]]; then
    printf "STATE: Starting backup of MySQL databases\n" >> "$logfile"
    mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/custom/files/my.cnf --single-transaction -u root --all-databases | gzip > "$backup_dir"/"$hostname"_"$datetime"_all_mysql_dbs.gz;
  else
    printf "ERROR: mysqld not installed\n" >> "$logfile"
  fi
fi
```

However, when running from root's crontab, it's running the else statement. In the log, I see `ERROR: mysqld not installed`, even though `mysqld` is definitely installed. The rest of the script runs fine (e.g., backing up directories, etc...).

If I run the code below as root, it correctly shows `mysqld` as being installed.

```
root@db03:~# if [[ -x "$(command -v mysqld)" ]]; then
>   printf "STATE: Starting backup of MySQL databases\n"
> else
>   printf "ERROR: mysqld not installed\n"
> fi
STATE: Starting backup of MySQL databases
```

In addition, if I run the entire script as root, it works correctly. It's only failing when running from crontab. What am I missing? Do I need an environment variable? Is it an issue with root's PATH?

```
root@db03:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

This is running on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with the bash package `4.4.18-2ubuntu1.1`.

Comment: What is `command`??

Comment: Try this: add `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` somewhere near the top of the crontab file.

Comment: Yep, the classic crontab does not have the environment the user does, so it does not do the same thing.  Either set the variables in the script, or you could source the .bashrc of the user as a first thing to do in the script.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - ```command``` is a program to see info about other programs. ```Execute a simple command or display information about commands```. It's a way to see if something is installed, like ```which```.

Comment: Thank you @Roadowl and Nic3500, I added the PATH and it worked! Roadowl, can you make this an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -- add:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

somewhere near the top of the crontab file.